# Laravel FormRequest does not read Form Data type request

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to working with Laravel `FormRequest` and I facing and issue with it when I the request is `Form Data`, It does not read the request but When I send the request like `Request Payload` it works fine dont Know what is the issue.

```
public function updateRecord($recordUnit)
{
    if($this->file('logo'))
    {
        $urlImage = $this->uploadFileEdit($this->file('logo'), $recordUnit->logo, $this->name);
    }

    $recordUnit->update([
         'col1' => $this->name,
          
     ]);
    $recordUnit->users()->syncWithoutDetaching($this->input('user_id', []));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: added code the formrequest